# Raspivid: 'ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR is called too late' & stream keeps freezing

Tags: raspivid

First post here, hopefully i'm in the right place :)

I'm attempting to stream low-latency video from my Raspberry Pi to my Windows PC using Raspivid and VLC.  I'm no expert on this stuff and i'm mainly following tutorials and trying to understand what I can.  I'm streaming over RTSP.

Here is my code for starting the stream on the Pi.  I've used some variations of this that i've found online, but it generally remains the same:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -n -w 600 -h 400 -fps 15 -rot 180 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264
```

I connect on Windows in VLC using the address:

```
rtsp://192.168.1.2:8554/
```

I can start the stream on the Pi and it runs through code, only throwing the following three errors on different lines.  In VLC, I can *open* the stream without issue.

```
main stream error: unknown query 0x30e in demux_vaControlHelper
main interface error: no suitable interface module
main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
```

Once I get to the stream in VLC though, it freezes and the Pi's terminal gives the following errors:

```
 main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1261 ms)
```

...then buffers to 100% before:

```
main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR is called too late (pts_delay increased to 2939 ms)
```

...and this buffering and then error loop repeats continuously until right before I terminate the program where it gives this error:

```
main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (jitter of 6511 ms ignored)
main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 15860001: no reference clock
main decoder error: Could not convert timestamps 0, 0 for h264
```

Every time the stream buffers, the stream unfreezes and I get some movement in VLC, but nothing usable.

I've tried adding the following flags to my starting command without luck:

- :network-caching=3000
- :clock-jitter=0
- --network-caching
- --file-caching

Nothing i've found has worked to solve this so far.  If anyone has a solution, I would be grateful to hear it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tests on my pi showed that this message vanishes when you set -fps to 50 or above.

Comment: This does seem to fix my immediate issue, which is awesome.  However, my stream still has a 2-3 second delay that I can't seem to remedy.  Any thoughts on what could cause that?

Comment: @BenjaminHogervorst did you ever get this to work without the 2-3s delay?

Answer (score 11):

Use the *--h264-fps* option to suggest input stream fps to VLC.

raspivid -o - -t 0 -n -w 600 -h 400 -fps 15 -rot 180 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264 **--h264-fps=15**

Answer (score 1):

This should be the accepted answer.
Use the same value for `raspivid -fps` and `cvlc --h263-fps=` to avoid `vlc` reading more/less frames than `raspivid` delivers.